# udev rule trouble on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbrian) using an ACR122U card reader

Tags: linux, udev, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get my ACR122U usable by all users on my Pi. I have the drivers installed correctly and `nfc-list` is working for root:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/udev/rules.d# nfc-list
nfc-list uses libnfc libnfc-1.7.1-11-gbb9babb
NFC device: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
```

However, it is not working for my user:

```
skrrp@raspberrypi ~ $ nfc-list
nfc-list uses libnfc libnfc-1.7.1-11-gbb9babb
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb        Unable to claim USB interface (Operation not permitted)
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_usb:001:004
```

`lsusb` reports:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/udev/rules.d# lsusb
[...]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 072f:2200 Advanced Card Systems, Ltd
```

And the device file is:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/udev/rules.d# ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/004
crw-rw-r-T 1 root root 189, 3 May  8 10:11 /dev/bus/usb/001/004
```

I have created `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-udev.rules` containing:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="072f", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2200", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

But I am still unable to access the device as a user, after rebooting and replugging the device. My user is a member of `plugdev` but I am really aiming for any user to use this device (permissions `0666`).

Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with my `udev` rule.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but more than likely the reason is because `/lib/udev/rules.d/92-libccid.rules` is being executed by `udev` after `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-udev.rules`.

rename `10-udev.rules` to say `93-udev.rules` and it should work.

Also `# udevadm trigger` should reload the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, but not by using my custom rule.

I edited `/lib/udev/rules.d/92-libccid.rules` that was provided by `libccid` and added `MODE="0666"` to the generic reader line in that file.